# VS Designer Now Showing MainMenu

Tags: c#, winforms

I can't seem to fix this issue (which i hope is small) i have somehow when adding a ContextMenu did something to have the MainMenu bar not show up when i debug, if i click on the "MainMenu" in the designer (1st image) the menu bar shows up in the designer fine:

[image: Designer:]

But if i click off it, then click on another control like:

[image: Other Control:]

The MainMenu disappears from the designer, when i build / debug the MainMenu is gone, is there a way to fix this easily enough (i assumed it would be as simple as checking a setting but googling did not return anything that i saw that was helpful)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Open `Document Outline` from `View` menu, and then reorganize the main menu strip.

Comment: It is not obvious how a StatusStrip turned into a giant yellow blob.  But "giant" is surely the problem, not enough space to fit both and somebody is going to lose.  Keep a status strip as a modest strip at the bottom of the UI.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your MainMenu has ended up hidden behind your other controls. Try right clicking on the main menu and selecting `Bring To Front`. If you can't right click on it, right click on the control that's filling the rest of the form and select `Send to back`.

When you click on a menu control in the component tray it will always show it at the top of the screen (even if you click on a ContextMenu).

One other thing worth doing is to open the Document Outline window from the View->Other Windows menu in Visual Studio. This gives you a hierarchichal view of all the controls on the current form. You should be able to see your main menu here (unless you've somehow removed it from your form!)